# Not install all files in site_packages using setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

When i install software(XYZ) using setup.py file using command "python setup.py install" it copy only files present in parent directory to the folder present in site_packages/XYZ .in setup file i define all packages and data_files which i want to use. Software package structure

```
XYZ
   __init__.py
   main.py
   test1.py
   vector
         __init__.py
         vector1.py
         vector2.py
   exlib
        __init__.py
        lib1.py
        lib2.py
```

when install using setup.py install command it copy only main.py,test1.py files in XYZ folder present in site_packages . i want to copy all files present in xyz folder when i run install command . how i modify setup file or any other way to do this.

Comment: Please provide `setup(...)` portion of your `setup.py`

Comment: A coherent question and related files please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your setup.py needs to have:

```
packages=['vector', 'exlib'],
```

Comment: now it include all folder with only python files how to include all other format files present in folder

Comment: data_files option not include files in install directory

Comment: The three things to look at here are data_files, MANIFEST.in and include_package_data

Comment: in data_files i define all other file (XML file) and when i install then new folder created in /usr is it possible to create the new folder in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/XYZ